# What is a standard implementation of upgradable ethereum Token contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain

I've readed some code of ethereum Token contracts, such as [this one](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb64ef51c888972c908cfacf59b47c1afbc0ab8ac#code)

In this code, it does **2 things** for upgradable:

- a contract interface or something like a "abstract contract" called "**UpgradeAgent**" which new contract needs to implement by derive from it.
- a function called "**upgrade**" in contract which may need to upgrade in future.

here is the code of function "**upgrade**"

```
  function upgrade(uint256 value) public {
      UpgradeState state = getUpgradeState();
      if(!(state == UpgradeState.ReadyToUpgrade || state == UpgradeState.Upgrading)) {
        // Called in a bad state
        throw;
      }

      // Validate input value.
      if (value == 0) throw;

      balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], value);

      // Take tokens out from circulation
      totalSupply = safeSub(totalSupply, value);
      totalUpgraded = safeAdd(totalUpgraded, value);

      // Upgrade agent reissues the tokens
      upgradeAgent.upgradeFrom(msg.sender, value);
      Upgrade(msg.sender, upgradeAgent, value);
  }
```

It's seems like : **Sub caller's balance which stored in old contract, and then add them in new contract by call the NewContract's function "upgradeFrom"**.

#### Now I have a confuse with this design:

Can anyone call NewContract's function "upgradeFrom" directly?

- If they can, will they add thier balance in NewContract while hold their balance in OldContract?
- If they can't, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function "upgradeFrom" have to check that it is called by OldToken address. You'll have to implement this in your future NewContract.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how to make sure if the caller is OldToken address in method 'upgradeFrom'? will the value of msg.sender be the address of OldToken?

Comment: While deploying NewContract you have to pass and store OldToken address in it. And then check it there like this:
`function upgradeFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public {
 require(msg.sender == oldTokenAddress);
 /* ... and so on, then deliver new tokens */
}`